# update content ckeditor

Tags: javascript, textarea, ckeditor

I'm trying to update the content of my ckeditor but it didn't works

```
<textarea id="monday" class="ckeditor" name="monday" >1</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#monday').val('test');
        CKEDITOR.instances.monday.updateElement();
        alert( $('#monday').val());
    },1000)
</script>
```

but I always having 1 in my ckeditor and the alert return

1

(1 with p but it didn't appear)

this is CKEditor 4.0

I ever read post about this on but it was an oldest version

Thanks

edit: 2nd test

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#monday').val('test');
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
    alert( $('#monday').val());
},5000)
</script>
```

But it didn't works

Edit 3rd test

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#monday').val('test');
    $('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
    console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
    console.log($('#monday').val())
    });
},5000)
</script>
```

I have all the time

1

in my console

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#monday').val('test');
    $('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
    var $textarea = $(this);
    console.log($('#monday').val())
    });
},5000)
</script>
```

return test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this another option

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').each(function () {
   var $textarea = $(this);
   $textarea.val(CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].getData());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I find

CKEDITOR.instances.monday.setData( '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>' );

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you remove this line

CKEDITOR.instances.monday.updateElement(); ?

Comment: are testing in chrome? check the javascript console if tell you some error

Comment: try this 

    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
      CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();}

Comment: I try but I always 1 in alert and in my ckeditor, I edit my first post, and I have no errors